# Trouble loading parity wallet from mnemonic phrase

Tags: parity, parity-wallet

When attempting to restore my parity wallet using the mnemonic phrase, a wallet that is different from the wallet i want to access is loaded. I can view my account and its balance of etherscan, but parity wont load it through the phrase. Can any one suggest anythign to help?

Comment: Are you sure you have the right mnemonic phrase, perhaps some word is not correct? I'd try MyEtherWallet as an alternative to open your wallet. But if you didn't have a backup there's not much that can be done.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. yeah i dont have a .json back up and am sure it is the right mnemonic phrase. MyEtherWallet took away the option to load from mnemonic phrase.

Comment: I think you should aks in some of the parity support channels, perhaps you can use an old version of MyEtherWallet.

Comment: How did you generate the phrase in first place?